# Code Optiomiztion - Converting List Of Values Into Columns

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, concatenation

I have a dataframe that has the user id in one column and a string consisting of comma-separated values of item ids for the items he possesses in the second column. I have to convert this into a resulting dataframe that has user ids as indices, and unique item ids as columns, with value 1 when that user has the item, and 0 when the user does not have the item. Attached below is the gist of the problem and the approach I am currently using to solve this problem.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame([[100, '10, 20, 30'],[200, '20, 30, 40']], columns=['userid','listofitemids'])
print(temp)

temp.listofitemids = temp.listofitemids.apply(lambda x:set(x.split(', ')))

dat = temp.values

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1]*len(dat[0][1])], index = [dat[0][0]], columns=dat[0][1])
for i in range(1, len(dat)):
    t = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1]*len(dat[i][1])], index = [dat[i][0]], columns=dat[i][1])
    df = df.append(t, sort=False)
df.head()
```

[image]

However, this code is clearly inefficient, and I am looking for a faster solution to this problem.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: My bad. Modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `str.split` with `explode` then `crosstab`

```
s = temp.assign(listofitemids=temp['listofitemids'].str.split(', ')).explode('listofitemids')
s = pd.crosstab(s['userid'], s['listofitemids']).mask(lambda x : x.eq(0))
s
Out[266]: 
listofitemids   10  20  30   40
userid                         
100            1.0   1   1  NaN
200            NaN   1   1  1.0
```

Comment: Got my code that was taking 6.6 seconds down to 0.19 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PrathameshMahankalP yw :-) happy coding man , do not forget to accept it :-)